# Calculating error in sampling

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, binomial-distribution, error

I have a certain population U.  The members x of U each either satisfy or don't satisfy a property p.  That is, p(x) is either true or false for each x in U.

I want to get an estimate of the fraction of members of U that satisfy p.  I do this by repeatedly sampling from U (with replacement) for some fixed time such as 60 seconds.  (This is a computer program I'm talking about.)

After sampling n items, I conclude the proportion is the number of items I found for which p is true divided by n.  Let f be this fraction (with 0 <= f <= 1).

That's all simple enough.  What I want to know is whether I can establish (a reasonably tight) upper-bound, b, on the error of f.

I naively assumed that the error b would be the abs(f - f') where f' is the fraction calculated after n - 1 samples.  From experimentation, I discovered this assumption was wrong.

Is there a way to get a reasonably tight bound b?

Comment: What do you mean by "reasonably tight"? Do you mean (a) a bound unlikely to be violated in practice or (b) a bound that, if made even narrower, would often be violated?  The two are opposite: (a) would be a conservatively large bound while (b) would be as small as possible. I ask this because (b) seems to conform with the conventional idea of a "tight" bound whereas you have accepted a reply that implicitly assumes you meant the opposite, (a).

Comment: I mean (a) a bound unlikely to be violated in practice.

Comment: Then the best possible answer to your question, Paul, is $b=1$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By sampling with replacement the number of selected items having p true out of the total selected will be binomial with parameter n and r where r is the actual proportion having p true.  If X is the number having p true then X/n is an unbiased estimate of r and its variance is r(1-r)/n.  Now since r(1-r) is maximized at r=1/2 the absolute bound on the variance is 1/(4n). So the standard deviation for X/n the estimate of f is < 1/(2√n).  So that is a guaranteed bound on the standard deviation of the estimate.